# Getting values from XML via php

Tags: php, xml

So my XML looks like this

```
<ApiResponse xmlns="http://api.namecheap.com/xml.response" Status="ERROR">
   <Errors>
      <Error Number="1011102">
      API Key is invalid or API access has not been enabled
      </Error>
   </Errors>
   <Warnings/>
   <RequestedCommand/>
   <Server>PHX01SBAPI02</Server>
   <GMTTimeDifference>--7:00</GMTTimeDifference>
   <ExecutionTime>0</ExecutionTime>
</ApiResponse>
```

How can I access the Error **Number** and the **Text**  `Api Key is invalid..`.

I tried :

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_string);
var_dump($xml['Errors']);
var_dump($xml->Errors->Error);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you parsed the xml? If not, you need to do that first, what you have shown is just a string, not an array or object.

Comment: @jeroen

Yes, I've parsed it. updated the question.

Comment: Working with xml is a pain, you can get the results that you need by casting the second option to a string: `var_dump((string) $xml->Errors->Error);`

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:** Try this..

```
$xmlArray = simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo $xmlArray->Errors->Error->attributes()->Number; //Number
echo $xmlArray->Errors->Error[0];                    //Text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access attributes as though they are elements of an array, so using your XML and

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_string);
echo "Number:".$xml->Errors->Error['Number'].PHP_EOL;
echo "Text:".(string)$xml->Errors->Error.PHP_EOL;
```

gives...

```
Number:1011102
Text:
      API Key is invalid or API access has not been enabled
```